# Delete all dataframe entries which are identical in one column but different in another

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider this pandas dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'animal': ["dog", "dog", "dog", "cat", "snake", "dog", "snake", "cat", "goat", "bird"],
               'label': [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]})
```

I want to remove *all* entries wherever the label does not match *all* animals. For example, dog is labelled with '0' three times, but the fourth time it is labelled '1', so I would then like to remove *all* dog entries. For the other animals, they are all labelled correspondingly, and thus I would like to keep the rest, so that the remaining dataframe will be:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'Column1': ["cat", "snake", "snake", "cat", "goat", "bird"],
               'label': [1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1]})
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`+`transform('nunique')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) to get the count of unique values per group.

If the count is 1, then keep the row using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df[df.groupby('animal')['label'].transform('nunique').eq(1)]
```

output:

```
  animal  label
3    cat      1
4  snake      0
6  snake      0
7    cat      1
8   goat      1
9   bird      1
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `transform` to get a series of unique values per group and compute a boolean mask by checking equality with 1.

```
mask = df.groupby('animal')['label'].transform('nunique').eq(1)
result = df[mask]
```

Details:

```
>>> df.groupby('animal')['label'].transform('nunique')
0    2
1    2
2    2
3    1
4    1
5    2
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    1
Name: label, dtype: int64
>>> df.groupby('animal')['label'].transform('nunique').eq(1)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5    False
6     True
7     True
8     True
9     True
Name: label, dtype: bool
```

Comment: [me too](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71129440/16343464) :p